# cypress how to make sure when click radio button A then text underneath is displayed

Tags: cypress

I am new to cypress and unsure which syntax or parameter to use to assert that the text is displayed when click on NO radio button.

This is the scrip action to NO button.

```
cy.get('#choose-answer_check-false').click();
```

the text displayed when click on NO radio button then. how do I assert it only displayed right after the click?

```
<div class="test-abc"><span>you have clicked NO</span></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cy.get('.test-abc').should('not.contain', 'you have clicked NO')
cy.get('#choose-answer_check-false').click();
cy.get('.test-abc').should('contain', 'you have clicked NO')
```

You simply first assert that the text is **not** present before clicking the button. This assumes that your `div` is still rendered before that click. If it previously contains no text or other text you can change the assertion accordingly.

Comment: I have added codes similiar like what you have shared. Just missing the first line, this is great assertion. cy.get('.test-abc').should('not.contain